# Hubot with Rocket.chat

Tags: node.js, hubot, rocket.chat

I am trying to integrate Hubot with rocketchat and make Hubot talk with  rocketchat.

The sources I am referring to are:

https://hubot.github.com/docs/

https://github.com/RocketChat/hubot-rocketchat

I have installed Nodejs and in Node.js command prompt I did:

```
mkdir myhubot
cd myhubot
yo hubot
```

**Questions I have:**

1. How do I understand if rocketchat is integrated with Hubot?
2. If I have not integrated rocketchat, how should I do it? (I did refer to https://github.com/RocketChat/hubot-rocketchat). Here, I want to understand how and where to set environment variables. Also, how exactly do I run Docker here?
3. When I do `docker export ROCKETCHAT_ROOM='https: //spree.chat/channel/'`

   It returns: `"Cowardly refusing to save to a terminal. Use the -o flag or redirect."`

   How can I resolve this?

Here is the screenshot:[image: MyHubot Rocketchat]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Rocket.chat have "Internal hubot" which is integraded and contain some simplest Hubot scripts. Ideal for testing and introduction to Hubot. You can find these scripts in `rocketchat/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/rocketchat_internal-hubot/node_modules/hubot-scripts/src/scripts/`.
If you wanna use more complex scripts, you must use external Hubot.

2.) Setup "Environment Variables" are different for each platform. For example, if you want set `ROCKETCHAT_ROOM` to `support`, you must use something like `env ROCKETCHAT_ROOM=support`. But this only applies to Linux OS. For Docker syntax is `-e ROCKETCHAT_ROOM=support`. If you running external Hubot on Windows, you probably must use something different.

3.) `ROCKETCHAT_ROOM` variable is not for URL of your channel. You must put here name of your chat room.

Comment: Hi i have completed setup and connected successfully. But hubot is not replying back to me.
I posted another question the the same
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52659602/rocket-chat-hubot-adapter-is-not-replying-back